# UINavigationBar titleTextAttributes does not update fully after reloading views

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

This is a tricky one.

Here is my storyboard for this demo:
[image: Storyboard]

The Settings screen segues to the My Color screen where users can choose either a dark or light color scheme for the app. When a change is made, I remove all views from the window and then re-add them to force the current view to immediately apply the changes via the UIAppearance proxy. So the color of the navigation bar and the nav bar's text color both change immediately.

Next, the user unwinds the segue to return to the Settings screen. On the Settings screen, the new color of the navigation bar is already applied. The new color of the nav bar's text is also already applied. However, for a brief instant while the segue is in transition, the nav bar still shows the old text color. The new text color is not shown until after the transition is complete. This results in a minor, but noticable, visual glitch as the nav bar's text suddenly changes from the old color to the new color.

[image]

To update the color of the nav bar text when the user flips the switch, I run the following code in the My Color screen's view controller. (The full project code up on Github at https://github.com/prinomen/social_demo2).

```
func switchValueDidChange(sender:UISwitch!) {
    if (sender.on == true) {
        colorIndex = 1 // nav bar is now black

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = black // set appearance proxy to the new color

        // Run this switch to set the textColor global var to match the preferred color scheme, based on the value of colorIndex.
        switch colorIndex {
        case 0: // white
            textColor = green
            statusBarTextIsBlack = true
        case 1: // black
            textColor = red
            statusBarTextIsBlack = false
        default:
            break;
        }

        // Update these appearance proxy items (they need the window to reload before they will manifest their changes).
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 22)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = textColor

        // Remove all views from the window and then re-add them in order to force the current view to immediately apply changes to UIAppearance.
        let windows : NSArray = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows
        for window in windows as! [UIWindow] {
            for view in window.subviews {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
                window.addSubview(view)
            }
        }

    } else {
        colorIndex = 0 // nav bar is now white

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = white // set appearance proxy to the preferred color

        // Run this switch to set the textColor global var to match the preferred color scheme, based on the value of colorIndex.
        switch colorIndex {
        case 0: // white
            textColor = green
            statusBarTextIsBlack = true
        case 1: // black
            textColor = red
            statusBarTextIsBlack = false
        default:
            break;
        }

        // Update these appearance proxy items (they need the window to reload before they will manifest their changes).
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 22)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = textColor

        // Remove all views from the window and then re-add them in order to force the current view to immediately apply changes to UIAppearance.
        let windows : NSArray = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows
        for window in windows as! [UIWindow] {
            for view in window.subviews {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
                window.addSubview(view)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aside from changing the color via the appearance proxy, I've also tried setting the color explicitly within the `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews` methods of the Settings screen view controller by running this line:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 22)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor]
```

But this results in the same issue. What I find confusing is that the other changes made via the appearance proxy are updated without encountering this issue. Only the `titleTextAttributes` property is troubled by this issue.

I thought that maybe iOS makes some kind of "snapshot" of the Settings screen when segueing to the My Color screen. Then when the segue is reversed, the "snapshot" with the old nav bar text color is used and the new color is not updated until the segue is finished. But if that were true, then why doesn't the navigation bar's `barTintColor` also experience the same problem? There must be a different way the reverse segue is handled, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Is there a way to apply the color change to the title text before the transition happens, in a way that affects the transition itself?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: A label's textcolor isn't animatable by default, which may be causing this. See [this old article](https://corecocoa.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/animatable-text-color-of-uilabel/#more-30) on the topic — you may be able to adapt its approach to achieve the effect you want

Comment: @AaronBrager - Thanks for the tip. I read the article. Seems like it would be possible to implement something like that in Swift. That could be useful to animate text color changes for a UILabel. But I'm not sure how I could use that to change the behavior of the UINavigationBar's title text color.

Comment: You could try subclassing UINavigationBar and replacing the title label with one that uses CATextLayer

Comment: I'm a new hand at this so that might be a little beyond me. But I could try it. I'll try searching SO to see if someone has done that before. Thanks for the advice.